# Disable WAL for app I don't have source code for?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an apk for an app and is not compatible with Android 9 because it now forces WAL instead of journal mode. Is there a way to disable WAL without access to the source code of the app?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the App's source, then I don't believe that you can change the mode.

Saying that, the most likely cause of the App not working is when a pre-existing database is used (copied from the assets folder).

If so, and you have access to another device where the App is working (i.e less than Android 9) and you have access to the database file (rooted devices may be needed). The there is a good chance copying that database file from the  after deleting the -shm and -wal files on the Android 9 device (again it may need to have been rooted) would work (although WAL would be used), but the issue is very likely purely the copying of the pre-existing database.

- I did a test using 5.0 and 10.0 devices (emulators) and this worked fine.

However, if you did have access to the code :-

You can use the SQLiteDatabase [**disableWriteAheadLogging**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase) method. You would execute this by overriding the **onConfigure** method if using a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper.

If not using a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper then you could set the journal mode using the [**journal_mode**](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) PRAGMA.

Comment: In the first solution, Doest it have to be a copy of the exact same database? I mean could it be the database for the same app but different user?

Comment: @JobFranco if the data isn't encrypted then any copy may work. I don't know about backup App's that may be of use, that's not an area that I've delved into.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it on the os itself?

Comment: @JobFranco possibly but very likely not simply, you'd perhaps get a more detailed response from [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)